# Bootstrap 3 VF javascript not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources, bootstrap

I am trying to implement the bootstrap accordion feature:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

So I upload the static resource and included in my VF  tag

But when I render the page, the section do not expand or collapse. Any ideas? I have tested in Chrome, Safari and Fireforx.

Comment: right click on your chrome browser and click on inspect element. Paste the console errors ( you can see a red X arrow with some number).

Comment: You will need to make sure that standardStylesheets is false and that you have included both the bootstrap styles + bootstrap javascript for it to work.

Comment: Could you add a cut down version of your page? (Just include the accordian part + the includescript  stuff and any javascript initialisation code)

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, ensure that `standardStylesheets="false"` is present in the page definition.
Then, make sure you have something similar to this (you need both css and javascript for this sort of bootstrap component to work:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.my_resource, 'my_resource/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.my_resource, 'my_resource/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}"/>
```

I also had some trouble getting the bootstrap component to load automatically and called my own in the `onload` function, ie:

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$('.collapse').collapse();
```

Finally, if it's still not working, do as the user @rao says - depending on what browser you are using, examine the console errors that appear.

Answer (score 1):

As @rao suggested, I inspected the element with the Chrome Console. I was missing the jQuery. I added the following lines to the head and now it works:

```
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"/>
```